# Proper Separation of Concerns When Using UnitOfWork?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I followed an online tutorial of the UnitOfWork pattern with Entity Framework as it has been awhile since I have used it.  I am confused as to why in the tutorial the DataContext is a parameter of the public UnitOfWork constructor.  This means if I use the UnitOfWork in another layer of the application, the other layer must be aware of the DataContext.  This does not seem like a good separation of concerns.  Am I missing something?

UnitOfWork:

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly PurchasingDataContext _context;

        public UnitOfWork(PurchasingDataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Items = new ItemRepository(_context);
            Manufacturers = new LabelerRepository(_context);
            Quotes = new QuoteRepository(_context);
            Vendors = new VendorRepository(_context);
            Contacts = new ContactRepository(_context);
        }



        public IItemRepository Items { get; private set; }
        public ILabelerRepository Manufacturers { get; private set; }
        public IQuoteRepository Quotes { get; private set; }
        public IVendorRepository Vendors { get; private set; }
        public IContactRepository Contacts { get; private set; }

        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IContactRepository Contacts { get; }
        IItemRepository Items { get; }
        ILabelerRepository Manufacturers { get; }
        IQuoteRepository Quotes { get; }
        IVendorRepository Vendors { get; }
        int Complete();
    }
```

Comment: "Am I missing something?" - Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused as to why in the tutorial the `DataContext` is a parameter of the `public` `UnitOfWork` constructor.

This is to make injecting the dependency into the UoW possible. By doing this, you can honor [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) easily.
With it, you can manage the scope of `DataContext` separately outside the UoW. This gives you much flexibility while using same UoW in different scenario (windows application vs web application for example). With this, you can expand database transactions the way you want.

> This means if I use the `UnitOfWork` in another layer of the application, the other layer must be aware of the `DataContext`.

Yes; but not entirely true. Yes, the instance of `DataContext` should be *managed* (create, inject and dispose) by calling layer. That's it. That layer does not need to interact with with this instance in any way.

> This does not seem like a good separation of concerns.

In continuation to earlier point, calling layer does not need to *know* how that instance work. All that part is abstracted in your UoW class. This is clean separation of concerns.

> Am I missing something?

Hope you know that now.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by asking why you are creating and exposing these repositories in your UnitOfWork. Having a single class that is responsible for a unit of work and the ownership of all of your repositories violates the Single Responsibility Principle. Your IUnitOfWork exposing every single repository that may or may not be needed by a caller violates the Interface Segregation Principle.

Instead of this approach, you should be using a dependency injection framework to manage the lifetimes of the context, repositories, and unit of work. The framework should ensure that one instance is created per request and shared across dependencies where needed.

A typical EntityFramework UnitOfWork would look similar to:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

with an implementation like:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly PurchasingDataContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(PurchasingDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```